# How long can halloumi be stored in refrigerator?

Tags: storage-method, refrigerator

I am planning to store a cooked meal of halloumi + couscous in the refrigerator.

How long can it be stored safely?

Comment: All cooked meals fall into the same “cooked dishes“ category in our generic Q/A, which was written to give general advice for all kinds of food combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Halloumi by itself can last a long time in the fridge.

The problem is the couscous which should last at most 1 or 2  days (or less) in the fridge depending on other ingredients in the preparation..

Comment: But once it’s in a meal, even the halloumi won’t keep longer - it’s out of the protecting salty brine.